# Any flaw in my logic ? Using Lists Java

Tags: java

I have a Java List called `List<Integer> busy`:

**Which has**

java.util.List : "[17, 21, 36, 22, 35, 23, 10, 6, 9, 11, 2, 19, 7]"

Now, i have a variable called `Int Capacity`

```
Capacity = 30;
```

I want to create each capacity record in a new list called `List<Integer> totallist`;
should be :

```
java.util.List : "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7 uptill 30]"
```

I was doing something like :

```
List<Integer> totallist = new ArrayList<>(capacity);

            for (int i = 0; i < totallist.size(); i++) {
                totallist.add(i); 
            }
```

I doubt if that is correct !

The next step is, i have another list called "**List free**"

Which should give me elements in the totallist minus those in the busy list.

I did something like :

```
List<Integer> free = new ArrayList<>(totallist);
free.removeAll(busy);
```

Is the logic correct ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: There is a flaw in the variable name `Capacity`. It is against naming convention

Comment: Any obvious reason to use a `List` instead of a `Set` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first problem that I see is that List.size() refers to the number of objects you have added to the the List, which will be zero initially until you actually add items after initialization.  You should do:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Capacity; i++) {
                totallist.add(i); 
            }
```

instead.

Edit:
As for the second half of your question, what you're asking isn't clear.  Do you mean you want to remove all of the items contained in one list if the other list also contains those items?

Comment: Your statement about `list.size()` referring to the non-null elements in the list is not correct.  I think what you mean to say, is that capacity and size are different concepts.  `size` is the number of elements in the list (null or not).  `capacity` refers to the size of the underlying array.  This array will have to be re-allocated when `size` grows beyond `capacity`.

Comment: @Submersed Thanks the problem was the loop. Now the logic works !! The next step was to remove all the "busy" elements from the totallist and put in a List.Which is working..

Comment: Cool deal, if it solved you problem please accept.  Otherwise, if you need any additional help relating to the same question please leave a comment.

Comment: @Submersed please edit your code so the totallist starts from 1. From the example it will be from 0-29. But what is needed is 1-30. I fixed that in my code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, however, while filling in the `totallist` you should do as following:

```
        int capacity = 30;
        List<Integer> totallist = new ArrayList<Integer>(capacity);

        for (int i = 1; i <= capacity; i++) {
            totallist.add(i); 
        }
```

It will fill in your list starting from 1 to 30 as follows:

```
java.util.List : "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7 uptill 30]"
```

However it is much better to use Set instead of List. In your last part you are removing all those numbers from List `free` which are in list `busy`. I am not sure what you want to do in the last part however.